# How to see Bazel build output?

Tags: bazel

How do you view stdout of bazel build as it happens?

I want to see all the logs written to stdout during a bazel build.

No one of these allows it to show the ls command before after it has failed

```
$ bazel build --show_progress --worker_verbose --verbose_failures --verbose_explanations=true -s --test_output=streamed :build
```

```
genrule(
  name = "build",
  cmd = "ls && sleep 60 && exit 1",
)
```

```
$ bazel build --show_progress --worker_verbose --verbose_failures --verbose_explanations=true -s --test_output=streamed :build
WARNING: --verbose_explanations has no effect when --explain=<file> is not enabled
INFO: Analyzed target //:build (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
SUBCOMMAND: # //:build [action 'Executing genrule //:build']
(cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_kevinsimper/f9e6a72c146c5ad83b84a8ebf539f8b2/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin \
  /bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; ls && sleep 60 && exit 1')
ERROR: /Users/kevinsimper/testproject/BUILD:1:1: Executing genrule //:build failed (Exit 1)
BUILD
TESTFILE
Target //:build failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 60.256s, Critical Path: 60.04s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to stream action stdout/stderr while it's executing, unless it's a test while using the `--test_output=streamed` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow an underhanded approach. If your build includes small number of lengthy actions, it is feasible to snoop for output in `bazel-out/_tmp/actions/std{err,out}-*` as it happens. This works for me with Bazel 3.1.0.